# laravel 4.2 Get generated html table / html from View/blade

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have the following generated jquery table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed quotation_table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
             <th width="5">QTY</th>
             <th width="150">Description</th>
             <th width="150">Amount Per Candidate</th> 
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>5</td>
              <td>some stuff</td>
              <td>$43</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I would like to get `<td>`  From the table in my **controller**
The normal way to get data is to use `Input::except('_token')` but I cannot get table data using this method.

How do I get table data using laravel 4.2 . Thanks :)

Comment: I think you would have to get the data you need from the table using `jQuery` and than make an `AJAX` call to that particular `method` in you `controller` with the data you have gathered.

Comment: i was thinking of using jquery to make hidden outputs of the <td> but that sounds hackash @musicvicious

Comment: What do you actually what to accomplish?

Comment: To submit a table. I added a answer, I still feel its a bit hackash but it works, let me know what you think @musicvicious

Comment: That was close to what i was about to suggest you.

Comment: LOL...yea.. I will leave the question open for a few weeks until the future me or you finds a solution @musicvicious

Answer (score 0):

This feels extremely hackash , Please comment if you have a better solution. but with this solution you can add a hidden token, validate and put this in a POST form

```
 {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'/sendLearnerDetails', 'class'=>'form-horizontal form-group ', 'method' => 'post')) }

<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed quotation_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="5">QTY</th>
        <th width="150">Description</th>
        <th width="150">Amount Per Candidate</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input name="qty" type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" value="5" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="description" type="text" class="form-control" id="description" value="some stuff" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="amountPerCanditate" type="text" class="form-control" id="amountPerCanditate" value="$43" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{{ Form::submit('Approve table', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

[Fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/kingleroyg/hdzq8jvg/)